# Catch all routes not working using regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I know that the first route will catch most of the paths. However, this will catch also /Product/Edit/blablabla (i'm using ASP.NET Routing Debugger):

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", 
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                          
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = @"\d{1,}" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Catch All",
            "{*path}",
            new { controller = "Error", action = "NotFound" }
        );
    }
```

But this is wrong! Why? If not an integer of min 1 of length, the first route should not match. I need also to handle not found coutroller and action... any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: What's the @ symbol denote to? Should it be inside of the quotes?

Comment: The `@` symbol tells the C# compiler to ignore escape codes.  For example: `@"\"` or `@"\""\"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should place expression in fourth parameter. Read this:

http://www.asp.net/LEARN/MVC/tutorial-24-cs.aspx

Listing 3.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Product",
    "Product/{productId}",
    new {controller="Product", action="Details"},
    new {productId = @"\d+" }
 );
```

The regular expression \d+ matches 
one or more integers. This constraint causes the Product route to match 
the following URLs:

- /Product/3
- /Product/8999

But not the following URLs:

- /Product/apple
- /Product

These browser requests will be 
handled by another route or, if there are no matching routes, a *The 
resource could not be found* error will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the [`MapRoute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505187.aspx) extension method.

The third parameter is a set of default values for the route parameters.

In your case, you're telling it that the default value for the `id` parameter is `\d{1,}`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: solved.

```
[HandleError]
```

will pass (automatically) the Exception Object to the Error.aspx View, which display the inner message.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error/NotFound" />
```

will call the ErrorController method "NotFound" which display a (static) aspx View.

Comment: You can define additional route for Edit with new {productId = @"\d+" }.